# Trying to run sql commands from java

Tags: java, sql, cmd, processbuilder

I am trying to run sql commands from java using ProcessBuilder. My problem si that i cant use the same cmd from different functions.
For example, i want to run an sql file when i press a button. After that, i want to maintain the connection to sql plus and commit or rollback the transaction by pressing other button. How to keep the process from a button to other?

My first button code:

```
public class MyExec {

    public static ProcessBuilder builder;
    public static Process p;
    public static BufferedReader bri;
    public static BufferedReader bre;
    public static BufferedWriter p_stdin;

     public static void executeScript(String scriptName, String alias, String path, TextArea txtArea) throws IOException {

     //obtaining sql script from a share folder
      NtlmPasswordAuthentication userCred = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain",
                    "user", "pass");
      SmbFile smbFile=new SmbFile("path"  + scriptName, userCred);
      File file = new File("D://" + scriptName);
      try (InputStream in = smbFile.getInputStream()) {
        Files.copy(smbFile.getInputStream(), file.toPath());
      }

      //init shell
      builder = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd" );
      builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
      try {
        p = builder.start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
      //get stdin of shell
      p_stdin =new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

      //executing commands in cmd
      try {
        p_stdin.write("sqlplus sys/sys@" + alias +" as sysdba");
        p_stdin.newLine();
        p_stdin.flush();
        p_stdin.write("@"+file.toPath());
        p_stdin.newLine();
        p_stdin.flush();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }

      // write stdout of shell (=output of all commands)
      String line;
      bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                   bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
      while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
        txtArea.appendText(line + "\n");
        System.out.println(line + "\n");
      }                
      while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
        txtArea.appendText(line + "\n");
        System.out.println(line + "\n");
      }

      System.out.println("Done.");
    }
```

}

Second button code:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     //commit the sql script which was run with the first button
     try {
       MyExec.p_stdin.write("commit");
       MyExec.p_stdin.newLine();
       MyExec.p_stdin.flush();
       MyExec.p_stdin.write("exit");
       MyExec.p_stdin.newLine();
       MyExec.p_stdin.flush();

       //output the result of commiting sql script
       String line;
       BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MyExec.p.getInputStream()));
       BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(MyExec.p.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = MyExec.bri.readLine()) != null) {
          txtArea.appendText(line + "\n");
          System.out.println(line + "\n");
        }
        MyExec.bri.close();
        while ((line = MyExec.bre.readLine()) != null) {
          txtArea.appendText(line + "\n");
          System.out.println(line + "\n");
        }
        MyExec.bri.close();
        System.out.println("Done.");
     } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     }

    }
    });
      //event on Commit button, running the thread above
    public void commit(ActionEvent e) {   
      t1.start();   
    }
```

Comment: Hint: you **never ever** have empty catch blocks. Then: read about java naming conventions. you dont use "_" in variable names; variable names go camelCase. And really important: you want us to spend **our** time to help you. So you take the time it takes to properly format/indent **all** of your input.

Comment: And then: avoid code duplication. The code for updating your txtArea is almost identical. Don't do that.

Comment: Please provide some more explanations of your code, what you are trying to do and what issue you are experiencing. It is hard to find an error in dozens or even hundreds lines of code. [Create a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @GhostCat, i dont use " " in my variables name, where u see that? Whatever, can u answer my question?

Comment: @MartinNyolt, at the first button, i have a Run button. When i press it my application opens a cmd, connect to sql plus and run a script. After that, the output is displayed in a Text Area. At the second button, i want to get the same cmd with the same connection to sql plus and press Commit/Rollback button, but it is not working.

Comment: Underbar, as in p_stdin?

Comment: @GhostCat Ok, it was my fault. But, can u help me with my problem?

Comment: The problem is: your code is such an unreadable mess that I feel inclined to avoid reading it. Why should I spent my time digging through your mess?

Comment: @GhostCat i am sorry about my code...

Comment: I have to admit: I got up very early, and I am tired. Normally I wouldnt mind I guess. But still: posting "easy-to-read" code helps with getting better answers. And for the record: it also helps you when you really focus on writing readable code: proper naming, formatting, avoiding code duplication and so on.

Comment: Don't give tiny bits of information in comments, but *update and improve your question*.

Comment: And seriously: this code is a **mess**. For example, your comments say that you would call exit .. but .. you dont. You just newlines there. Seriously: improve your code; delete this question, and start afresh.

Comment: @GhostCat, it's ok now?

Comment: Have a class say `QueryRunner` with methods like Connect, BeginTran, Commit/RollbackTran, Execute. Ensure your button listeners use the same instance of the above class.

Comment: @Serg can u give me an example, please?

Comment: See http://www.sql2o.org/ for example.

Comment: I spent 5 minutes re-formatting your code; to come to the conclussion: it is still extremely confusing. And just for the record: your whole question, and your responses ... to me that screams: you shouldnt be doing such work yet. You are missing a lot of knowledge about very basic things. Honestly: you have no clue what you are doing. And yet, you want to build an UI application that makes changes to a database. If I would be the owner of that DB, I wouldnt let you do that. Because, as said: you are creating the impression that you dont know what you are doing.

Comment: @Serg i cant use JDBC, i need to execute sql scripts with sql and pl/sql code..

Comment: @GhostCat, tell me what is confusing and i will try to explain you. Why are u wasting ur time  telling me things like an angry teacher? I need help. Can u help me? Yes or not.

Comment: sql2o.org  is just an example. Do it the way you need. You need a class wich persists while your app is running and can keep DB connection open.

Comment: @Serg i need to keep sql plus connection open, until i write exit..

Comment: @GhostCat, it's easy, i want to get the process from the first function and use it in the second...i dont want to make a new process because i need to keep DB connection...

Comment: Lets see: the one crucial point missing here: what is **MyExec**?

Comment: @GhostCat, look at my first post now, MyExec is a class for running cmd

Comment: If you mean Oracle Spl *Plus, this utility has no API to control it from other programm. So essentialy your question is how to create, persist and control OS terminal session,  your `p` i guess. You may wish to ask another question about it, this is not sql specific.

Comment: @Serg, yes i want to control OS terminal session. I can do this from first button, but i dont know how to use the same terminal session for the second button...

Comment: Why are you doing this through SQL*Plus? Nearly every SQL command can be run through plain JDBC. I think everything will be a **lot** easier for you if you simply ran your statements through JDBC

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Serg is giving you the right direction: you need a **clear** separation of concerns here. You don't write one application that somehow does everything in one place.

You start by defining an interface such as

```
interface SqlProvider {
  public void connectConnection() ... 
  public void beginTransaction() ...
  public void commit() ..
  public void rollback()
  public void endTransaction()
  public voide closeConnection()
```

each of them with reasonable parameters and throw lists.

Then you start implementing that interfaces; similar to what you have done within MyExec so far; but: you **hide** all that ProcessBuilder things from the users of your interface.

Meaning: in your current code, you have public fields; and you expect your "button" code to use those fields. And that is **wrong**. Instead, your button code should be calling (non-static!) methods on an instance of that interface. And the implementation of that interface makes sure that the correct things happen.

You absolutely do not continue your current approach (where one class opens streams, and other classes just "append" to those streams; or read from them).

Comment: what u say is not for a JDBC connection? yes, u are right. I am trying to open cmd from a function and append commands from other function

Comment: I am saying that **no matter** what you do; you should **abstract** from that. A user of that interface should not need to know. All he knows is that there are several methods that need to be called in a certain order; and that do meaningful things.

Comment: i know abot public fields, but i use them to win time, this is a test code, after o find a solution i will make it...

Comment: Seriously, that is what "abstractions" are about: I just made a proposal how things could look like. But one final thing: what exactly is your problem with your current code? I guess it is doing what you want it to do? Or are there errors/bugs?

Comment: So...from the first button, i open a cmd session, i connect to sql plus and i run a script. Until now, all is working. BUT, i am trying to get the same cmd session which i opened and append commands from the second button commit or rollback. HERE is my problem, the second button is not doing anything, it is not getting the cmd session..This is my main problem, the rest of the code, it doesn't matter, i will improve it, but tell me how to solve the problem of using the same cmd session from different functions...

Comment: Just guessing then: make your two BufferedReaders fields in MyExec, too. So instead of creating them afresh for the other button; just use the very same readers that the first code created.

Comment: The problem is: is not working is a not a helpful description. So, A): seriously consider deleting this question now; we are just stumbling around B) turn to the help center. read how to ask "code not working" questions C) write up a new better version, with a minimal example that shows your problem. As said; from looking at your code, it should be doing what you want it to do.

Comment: i dont have waht to put like a minimal example...it is not doing what i want to do